# Printing out a doubly linked list using a reference variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I was given this function to define and I'm a little confuse do how to do that. It's supposed to print out a linked list either forwards or backward.

```
void printList(List& source, bool direction)
{

}
```

So I understand that I will use the `direction` variable in an if statement but I don't know what do with the `source` variable. Here is my guess:

```
void printList(List& source, bool direction)
{
  ListNode *p = source;

  if(direction)
  {
    while(p)
    {
    cout << p->value<< " ";
    p->next
    }
  }

  else
  {
    while(p)
    {
    cout << p->value<< " ";
    p->next
    }
  }
}
```

Also just so there is not confusion for you guys I am using another class callded `ListNode` class that has three values: `next` , `previous` , `value`.

Comment: Why not `const List& source` as parameter actually?  `p->next` isn't a valid statement anyways.

Comment: You probably mean `p = p->next;` and `p = p->previous;`.

Comment: I noticed you're going to ask low quality questions here frequently. I urgently recommend you to read all of the [articles from the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) how to put good questions in future. Though I like your avatar, that doesn't help much to improve the quality of your questions :-P ...

Comment: Is `List` a pointer type?  Looks like you are assigning (and converting) from a `LIst` (non-pointer) type to a *pointer to `ListNode`*.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ListNode *p = source;
> ```

is actually invalid syntax, since `source` isn't a pointer type. You want to assign the address:

```
ListNode *p = &source;
           // ^
```

Supposed you have a double linked list, the statements to proceed in a particular direction will be

```
p = p->next;
```

or

```
p = p->previous;
```

depending on the implied semantics of the `direction` value.

---

Also note, that it's sufficient to provide a `const` reference for the parameter, if you're not intend to have changes seen outside of the function:

```
 void printList(const List& source, bool direction)
             // ^^^^^
```